# Header refresh no funciona por headers already sent

Tags: php, html

Os comento mi problema, en mi web para un proyecto de clase, tengo una clase Form.php que gestiona todos los formularios que tengo (como formularios para login, para registro, etc.)

Voy a exponer de ejemplo el login y explico la lógica de funcionamiento. Primero en un script login.php:

```
//Parte de su contenido:
<body>
    <?php
        require("include/comun/cabecera.php");
    ?>
    <div class="contenido">
        <?php
            $form = new FormularioLogin();
            $html = $form->gestiona();
            echo $html;
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        require("include/comun/sidebarDer.php");
        require("include/comun/pie.php");
    ?>
</body>
```

Este código crea un FormularioLogin y mediante su padre form, lo gestiona de forma que devuelve en la variable $html el codigo que muestra el formulario (también tiene cosas internas para controlar errores y tal)
La función gestiona() funciona de tal manera que si existen errores en el proceso, vuelve a mostrar el formulario, pero en caso de no existir errores, realiza una redirección, y es aquí donde encuentro problemas ya que en modo local funciona perfectamente pero en el servidor, encuentro el error "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"

El código es el siguiente:

```
 public function gestiona() {   
        if ( ! $this->formularioEnviado($_POST) ) {
            return $this->generaFormulario();
        } else {
            $result = $this->procesaFormulario($_POST);
            if ( is_array($result) ) {
                return $this->generaFormulario($result, $_POST);
            } else {
                header('Location: '.$result);
            }
        }  
}
```

Además, he intentado en lugar de realizar el header en Form, envíar la cadena con la dirección que contiene $result y realizar el header en login.php, pero sigue saltando el error y no realizando la redireccion.

Comment: Lo ideal para evitar este tipo de problemas es tener toda la lógica en la parte superior (antes de la etiqueta `<body>`) y dejar entre el código `html` solo las variables o funciones que tengan salidas simples de datos. De esa forma todos los _header(...)_ se ejecutan antes de enviar una salida y se evitan estos problemas.

Comment: Funcionando! Gracias!